# Computing weighted marginal averages in a table with addmargin

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable

I create a table with the average number of days that people have participated in a survey broken out by country and sex.

```
   tbl_tmp <- df_tmp1 %>% 
                 group_by(country, Sex) %>%      
                 summarize(Mean_Days_Used = round(mean(Days_Used), 1)) %>% 
                 spread(Sex, Mean_Days_Used)
```

The result is

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   country [10]
   country Female     Male       `No Response`
   <chr>   <drtn>     <drtn>     <drtn>       
 1 AU       23.3 days    NA days NA days      
 2 CA       60.8 days  46.5 days NA days      
 3 FR         NA days  17.0 days NA days      
 4 GB       52.0 days  62.8 days 31 days      
 5 HK         NA days 125.0 days NA days      
 6 IE      109.6 days 100.5 days NA days      
 7 JP         NA days  10.0 days NA days      
 8 NZ      118.0 days   8.0 days NA days      
 9 PL         NA days    NA days 27 days      
10 US       35.2 days  41.7 days 86 days
```

I would now like to add marginal averages to each row and column, but there is two twists:

1. I want a weighted average (weighted by the proportion of entries in each cell), not just a simple row wise or column wise average
2. I need to deal with NAs, which arise when there are no respondents from a given country with a given sex

I would normally use `addmargins` to add all the marginal sums / means etc., but this fails to account for the relative frequency of entrants in each cell, and, in addition, chokes on NA's. By way of example if there are 10 male respondents and 20 female respondents in New Zealand, I would like row 8 of the marginal column to be (118 * 10 + 8 * 20 + 0 )/30 = 44.67. A similar argument applies to the weighted column means.

How ought I to compute these weighted averages?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: It'd help if you can provide `dput` for `df_tmp1`, before you summarize.  Or at least a subset of `dput` that contains a few countries' worth of data.

Comment: `df_tmp1 <- tibble(
                            UserId = LETTERS[1:11],
                            country = c(rep("AU", 5), rep("CA", 6)),
                             Sex = c(rep("Female", 3), rep("Male", 2), "Female", rep("Male", 2), rep("No Response", 3) ),
                             Days_Used = 1:11
                             )`

Comment: How are you counting marginal column? `(Average_Female_days * count_of_male + Average_male_days * count_of_female + Average_No_Response)/Total_count_of_country` ?

Comment: In any given row (i.e. for any given country), I want to compute `(Average_Female_days_in_this_country * count_of_female_in_this_country + Average_male_days_in_this_country * count_of_male_in_this_country + Average_No_Response_days_in_this_country * count_of_No_Response_in_this_country)/Total_count_in_this_country`. By analogy, the average at the bottom of each column is the weighted averarge across all countries of the average days by respondents of a given sex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_tmp1 %>% 
  group_by(country, Sex) %>%      
  summarise(Mean_Days_Used = mean(Days_Used),
            n = n()) %>%
  mutate(total = (Mean_Days_Used * n)/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-n, -Mean_Days_Used) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sex, values_from = total) %>%
  mutate(mean = rowMeans(.[-1], na.rm = TRUE)) -> df1


result <- rbind(df1, data.frame(country = 'Total', 
                     t(colMeans(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE)), check.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: This is headed in the right direction, but is not there fully as it is not in a tabular format.  want 1 row per country and 1 column per sex. with totals below and to the right. I suppose I could drop the column `n', and keep `total`, but I still lack column summaries

Comment: I have updated the answer to add row/column summaries in the data. @ThomasPhilips

Comment: This works annd is much more compact tha my clumsy solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a clumsy answer that does work, but surely here must be a cleaner way

```
   Avg_by_Bucket <- df_tmp1 %>%
                       group_by(country,Sex)%>%
                       summarize(Mean_Days_Used = round(mean(Days_Used), 1))%>%
                       spread(Sex, Mean_Days_Used)
    
    Avg_by_country <- df_tmp1 %>%
                        group_by(country)%>%
                        summarize(Mean_Days_Used = round(mean(Days_Used), 1))
    
    Avg_by_Sex <- df_tmp1 %>%
                    group_by(Sex)%>%
                    summarize(Mean_days_used_by_sex = round(mean(Days_Used), 1))%>%
                    spread(Sex, Mean_days_used_by_sex)
    
    Overall_Avg <- df_tmp1 %>%
                      summarize(Mean_Days_Used = round(mean(Days_Used), 1))
    
df_tmp_a <- full_join(Avg_by_Bucket, Avg_by_country, by = 'country')
df_tmp_b <- bind_cols(Avg_by_Sex, Overall_Avg)

table_3  <- bind_rows(df_tmp_a, df_tmp_b)
table_3[dim(table_3)[1], 1] <- "Mean_Days_Used"
column_to_rownames(table_3, var = "country")
```

when applied to my toy data set

```
> df_tmp1
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   UserId country Sex         Days_Used
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>           <int>
 1 A      AU      Female              1
 2 B      AU      Female              2
 3 C      AU      Female              3
 4 D      AU      Male                4
 5 E      AU      Male                5
 6 F      CA      Female              6
 7 G      CA      Male                7
 8 H      CA      Male                8
 9 I      CA      No Response         9
10 J      CA      No Response        10
11 K      CA      No Response        11
```

which was generated using

```
df_tmp1 <- tibble(
                  UserId = LETTERS[1:11],
                  country = c(rep("AU", 5), rep("CA", 6)),
                  Sex = c(rep("Female", 3), rep("Male", 2), "Female", rep("Male", 2), rep("No Response", 3) ),                              
                  Days_Used = 1:11
                  )
```

gives me what I want:

```
               Female Male No Response Mean_Days_Used
AU                  2  4.5          NA            3.0
CA                  6  7.5          10            8.5
Mean_Days_Used      3  6.0          10            6.0
```